# See exact manifest diff for `kubectl scale` before executing

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any way to see what is going to exactly happen when I do `kubectl scale ...` before I actually run the command?

I would like to do something like:

```
kubectl scale --dry-run --diff ...my-deployment --replicas=2
```

and see something like

```
...
    name: my-deployment
...
-     replicas: 1
+     replicas: 2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward answer is it's not possible.

I don't know your intention, but if you can use option `--current-replicas` in some cases.

```
--current-replicas=-1: Precondition for current size. Requires that the current size of the resource match this value in order to scale.
```